# ChatGPT - what do we flag as?

Tags: discussion, flagging, chatgpt

How do we best flag [fairly obvious] suspected ChatGPT answers? Do we need to flag for a mod every time, or spam… or…?

These are usually already attracting human attention - comments underneath, a downvote or two along with the usual style of opening gambit, re-stating the question, so they're pretty easy to recognise…

> How do we flag ChatGPT?
>
> To flag ChatGPT you have several options… ;)

The answers are usually barely relevant or hopelessly inaccurate b*ll*cks too, of course ;)

Comment: mod flag as suspected chatgpt

Comment: The user will either need to be suspended otherwise dealt with, so custom flagging to get some human eyes on it is best.

Comment: Does someone want to drop that into an answer - I mean, I get the idea, I just like putting big green ticks on things ;))

Comment: If someone has just pasted an AI answer, doesn't that qualify as plagiarism?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd go with a custom flag. If you've run it through a chat gpt tester, mentioning it's always handy.

We also tend to suspend chatgpt users and custom flags are always human-handled, unlike say spam flags so it'll also ensure we don't miss them.

Comment: What if it's also spam?

Comment: hm, they caught on fast didn't they? Spam flag I'd guess -   I think some of the mods keep an eye on smokey anyway

Comment: Worth noting, "chat gpt testers" are notoriously unreliable, and often flag clearly-non-gpt generated text (such as documents written years ago) as being from ChatGPT.